# Remove boxes under preservation of shape

Tags: code-golf, array

*This challenge is specific to languages of the APL family. Although it might be solvable in other languages, please do not expect this to be easy as it depends on some specific concepts of this language family.*

Many array oriented languages have the concept of a box (also called enclosure). A box encapsulates an array, hiding its shape. Here is an example of a boxed array:

```
┌─┬───────┬─────┐
│0│1 2 3 4│0 1 2│
│ │       │3 4 5│
└─┴───────┴─────┘
```

This array was generated from the J sentence `0 ; 1 2 3 4 ; i. 2 3` and contains three boxes, the first containing the scalar `0`, the second containing a vector of shape `4`, and the third containing a matrix of shape `2 3`.

Some arrays of boxes look like they are plain arrays broken apart by boxes:

```
┌─┬───────────┐
│0│1 2 3 4    │
├─┼───────────┤
│5│ 9 10 11 12│
│6│13 14 15 16│
│7│17 18 19 20│
│8│21 22 23 24│
└─┴───────────┘
```

The previous array was generated from the J expression `2 2 $ 0 ; 1 2 3 4 ; (,. 5 6 7 8) ; 9 + i. 4 4`.

Your goal in this challenge is to take an array like that and remove the boxes separating the subarrays from one another. For instance, the previous array would be transformed into

```
0  1  2  3  4
5  9 10 11 12
6 13 14 15 16
7 17 18 19 20
8 21 22 23 24
```

Submit a solution as a monadic verb / function. The verb must work on arrays of arbitrary rank. You may assume that the shapes of the boxed arrays fit, that is, boxed subarrays adjacent on an axis have to have the same dimensions in all but that axis. Behaviour is undefined if they don't.

This challenge is *code golf.* The submission compromising the least amount of characters wins.

Comment: Which languages are considered part of the APL family?

Comment: @AlexA. Languages like APL, J, and K.

Comment: @randomra An array of boxes such that the arrays in the boxes if concatenated along the respective axes would form one large array. Imagine each boxed subarray to be a cuboid or rectangle and you put these together as specified by the boxes' positions to get a large cuboid or rectangle.

Comment: @randomra Your input would be considered invalid as the subarrays are not directly concatenable along the axes they would be concatenated.

Comment: Number of dimensions for the boxed array?

Comment: @randomra Arbitrary.

Comment: In the interest of making this less language-specific, why not provide the example also using simple nested array notation for other languages?

Comment: @MartinBüttner That would require a notation that can distinguish nested arrays from multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @FUZxxl Why? The first two levels would be treated as a 2D array of boxes, and the (up to 2) levels below that would be the normal arrays. Or could you actually have arbitrarily many dimensions of either in the challenge? If so, your own example is by far not enough and you should include at least 1D and 3D examples as well.

Comment: @MartinBüttner It's supposed to work with n-dimensional arrays of boxes where each box contains an array of arbitrary dimension as long as the constraints are met.

Comment: "You may assume that the shapes of the boxed arrays fit, that is, boxed subarrays adjacent on an axis have to have the same dimensions in all but that axis." So doesn't that mean `2 2$0;1 2 3 4;(,.5 6 7 8);9+i.4 4` is undefined behaviour? `1 2 3 4` doesn't have the same dimensions as `0` or `9+i.4 4` because the ranks don't even match.

Comment: @algorithmshark If one subarray has lesser rank than another, add leading axes with a dimension of one each until the ranks are equal.

Comment: @FUZxxl Do you have a nice solution for the question? (Couldn't ping/reach you in chat.)

Comment: @randomra No. I have some ideas involving ;"1 and transposing the matrices until we're out of boxes.

Comment: @FUZxxl I feel like you need dynamic rank (which doesn't exist AFAIK). (Hence my "code-generator" hack.) Would be interested to see how can you resolve that issue (or is it exist at all).

Comment: @randomra Rank can be an arbitrary noun, does not need to be a constant.

Comment: @FUZxxl Can't ping you in chat (because you haven't been there for some time) but `(<@(<;.1)~1,.2#:@i.@^<:@#) 'abc'` works for partitioning. (And I would like to see your solution for this challenge. :))

Answer (score 1):

## J, 73 chars

```
f=.3 :0
>".'z',~,(',"','&.>/',~":)"*1+i.#$z=.(,$~$,~1#~(#$y)-#@$)&.>y
)
```

Usage and tests:

```
   a=.2 2 $ 0 ; 1 2 3 4 ; (,. 5 6 7 8) ; 9 + i. 4 4

   f a
0  1  2  3  4
5  9 10 11 12
6 13 14 15 16
7 17 18 19 20
8 21 22 23 24

   f a,:a  NB. rank 3 test
0  1  2  3  4
5  9 10 11 12
6 13 14 15 16
7 17 18 19 20
8 21 22 23 24

0  1  2  3  4
5  9 10 11 12
6 13 14 15 16
7 17 18 19 20
8 21 22 23 24
```

Golfing and explanation coming tomorrow.

Comment: Your solutions looks like you took a sledgehammer to the problem and beat it with brute force until it ceased to exist.

Comment: @FUZxxl Exactly. Interested in nice solutions.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 39

```
f=:([:;(([:(;"1@|:)(;/&> ::]))&.>)@<"1)
```

Usage and tests

```
a=.2 2 $ 0 ; 1 2 3 4 ; (,. 5 6 7 8) ; 9 + i. 4 4
   f a
0  1  2  3  4
5  9 10 11 12
6 13 14 15 16
7 17 18 19 20
8 21 22 23 24
```

Comment: Is the name for v really needed? This csn be shortened I think.

Comment: good point. shortened

Comment: You can leave out some parentheses: `[:;([:;"1@|:;/&> ::])&.>@<"1` it's not needed to assign the verb to a name either.

Comment: This looks a little bit like it would only work with two-dimensional test-cases.